# extract text in rich text format from range

Tags: c#, office-interop, rtf, word-interop

How can I extract the RTF content from the Range (Microsoft.Interop.Word.Range class) of word document? Range has property named "Text" but it returns the plain text and not the RTF Text. So how I can get the RTF text from Range?

Comment: Did you try formatedtext as a quick guess?

Comment: yes. It doesn't help

Answer (score 2):

Word's native format is not RTF - a conversion is necessary to get Word Open XML (or binary) content as RTF. That means there are three possibilities:

1. Save the document to the RTF format (or copy the Range to a new document and save it to RTF format), then extract the RTF from the file.
2. Copy the Range to the *Clipboard*. Word puts its content in multiple formats on the Clipbord, including RTF. You should be able to extract the Clipboard content, therefore, as RTF.
3. Find (or create) a conversion tool that can convert Word Open XML to RTF. Extract the Word Open XML using `Range.WordOpenXML` to a string, then run that through the conversion tool.